# bootstrap modal keeps opening

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some problems with a modal window in bootstrap.

I have a button, and when I click it, it shows a modal window, but when I click the close button, it closes and straight away it opens again, continually, and I can not close it!!!

here is the code:

### html

```
<a href="">
        <span class="chatButtonDetails">
          <span class="icon-iconOnlyChat"></span>
          Chat now
         <div id="chatModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chat Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>chat chat chat</p>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </span>
      </a>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.chatButtonDetails').click(function() {
         $("#chatModal").modal('show');
         return false;
        });
    });
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

`Model is always outside of all content`- This is bootstrap convention.
Please change your HTML like this, it should work,

```
<a href="">
        <span class="chatButtonDetails">
          <span class="icon-iconOnlyChat"></span>
          Chat now

        </span>
      </a>
         <div id="chatModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chat Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>chat chat chat</p>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you have your modal inside your span element that you use to open.

close your span element like this and have your modal outside of it and it will work.

```
    <span class="chatButtonDetails">
          <span class="icon-iconOnlyChat"></span>
          <a href="#">Chat now</a>
         </span> 


<div id="chatModal" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chat Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>chat chat chat</p>  
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`</a>` Before close on `<div id="chatModal" class="modal fade">`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/DTcHh/4799/)